# c# inheritance of base class to template

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to write a framework which needs to implement a few functions. Now I need to access the base class functions from the framework, which does not work.

I need to inherit form a given class "Master"

```
public class MyClass : Master
{
   protected override void Initialize() {
     FunctionInMaster();
     VariableInMaster = true;
   }
}
```

Now I simply want to create a class that can be derived and implements Master functions.

```
public class MyFrameworkClass
{
   // framework override
   public void whatever() 
   {
     FunctionInMaster();
     VariableInMaster = true;
   }
}

public class MyClass : Master
{
   protected override void Initialize() {
     whatever();

     FunctionInMaster();
     VariableInMaster = true;
   }
}
```

How do I do that without instantiating "MyFrameworkClass" and passing a pointer of "this" to MyFrameworkClass?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not very clear and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do I get it right that you need to call `Master` method in `MyFrameworkClass`? In that case, you can either inherit from `Master` or `MyClass` or have it as a member (as you call it "passing this"). If you are trying to achieve something bigger, it would be necessary to know what the goal is in order to provide more (presumably design) advice.

Comment: sorry for that. So I need to derive from "Master". So, its essential that I derive MyClass from Master. The question is, how do I make use of a third class, i.e. "MyFramworkClass" which needs to call functions and set variables that are declared in Master. I can't inherit MyFrameworkClass from Master.

Comment: Why can't `MyFrameworkClass` inherit from `Master` (apart from the then poor name choice, an abstract class named `MyClassBase` or something similar would be better)?

Answer (score 0):

You can never have multiple inheritance in C# (and it's a very good thing, multiple inheritance is a nightmare), but you can invoke methods from other classes, or even have some composition.

```
public static class MyFrameworkClass
{

    // framework override
    public static void whatever(Master master) 
    {
        master.FunctionInMaster();
        master.VariableInMaster = true;
    }
}

public class MyClass : Master
{        
    protected override void Initialize() 
    {
        MyFrameWorkClass.whatever(this);

        FunctionInMaster();
        VariableInMaster = true;
    }
}
```

Don't try to do too many things with inheritance. Inheritance is a powerful tool, but not an universal one. Often composition is better suited to tackle a specific problem.

You could also have multiple levels of inheritance, if you need to access protected methods and you know you will reuse this code in other derived classes.

```
public class MyFrameworkClass : Master
{

    // framework override
    protected void whatever() 
    {
        FunctionInMaster();
        VariableInMaster = true;
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyFrameworkClass 
{        
    protected override void Initialize() 
    {
        whatever();

        FunctionInMaster();
        VariableInMaster = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, MyClass needs to derive Master. Nevertheless, the first solution works, but I was trying to circumvent passing the "Master" to MyFrameworkClass but seems to be the evil.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your comment: in both solutions I proposed, `MyClass` inherits from `Master`: directly in the first case and indirectly in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could change inheritance to be Master -> MyFrameworks -> MyClass, that is less advisable.  Is the intention to make sure deriving classes implement specific methods - in that case consider adding abstract methods to Master.  If you are unable to alter Master, you can change MyFrameworks to be an interface rather than a class.  MyClass can inherit multiple interfaces, but only one class.

Comment: unfortunately, MyClass needs to derive Master.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to access the base class [instance] functions from the framework

To call instance methods you need an instance.  There are three ways to do that:

- Inherit form the class and use `this` - you have already stated that you can't do this.
- Accept an instance of the base class and call methods on it - you have stated that you don't *want* to do this.
- *Create* an instance of the class and call methods on it.

Now `static` methods are different - you do not need an instance, but they can only use static fields, which would be shared across all instances of the class.  Since you use a non-static property in the base class, it's safe to assume that `static` is not an option, so you're stuck with one of the three options above.